# Java Sending Email with attachment, error on DataContentHandler

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

My scenario is this:

I have a web application, the user writes a message, attaches a file and sends the email.

I use JavaMail to send the mail like this but i have problem attaching the file to the message (my file is on Session):

```
        if (request.getSession().getAttribute("EMAIL_ATTACHMENT") != null) {
            UploadFile file = (UploadFile) request.getSession().getAttribute("EMAIL_ATTACHMENT");
            MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            mbp1.setContent(text, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
            MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            // attach the file to the message
            MyMailAttachmentDataSource fds = new MyMailAttachmentDataSource(file);
            mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            mbp2.setFileName(fds.getName());
            mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
            msg.setContent(mp, "text/plain");

        }
```

The code for MyMailAttachmentDataSource is this:

```
public class MyMailAttachmentDataSource implements DataSource{
    private UploadFile file; 
    public MyMailAttachmentDataSource(UploadFile file){
        this.file=file;
    }
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return file.getInpuStream();
    }
    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return file.getContentType();
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return file.getFileName();
    }
}
```

When i try to send the email, i get this exception

```
java.io.IOException: "text/plain" DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.writeTo(text_plain.java:97)
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:884)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1089)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1527)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:321)
at admin.email.JavaMail.SendEmail(JavaMail.java:403)
at admin.email.MailSend.SendMail(MailSend.java:86)
```

I tried to change the msg.contentType to "text/html" but still get the above Exception

```
"text/html" DataContentHandler requires String object, was given object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
```

Does anyone knows what causes this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email with attachment can not be of type `text/plain` or `text/html`, it should be `multipart/mixed`.

It seems, that it will be enough to change code line `msg.setContent(mp, "text/plain");` to
just `msg.setContent(mp);`